# Error: Cannot find module './config.json' Require stack: [...] {JS}

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The console keeps showing this error, the path is 100% correct. Did I write something wrong? Please help!

```js
const prefix = require('./config.json');

module.exports = {
 name: 'say',
 description: '...',
 execute(message, args) {
  const repeated = message.content
   .slice(prefix.length)
   .trim()
   .split(/ +/g);
  message.channel.send(repeated);
 },
};
```

Here's my folder structure:
[image: heres the ss!]

Comment: what's your folder structure like

Comment: Well apparently the module can't be found, can you post a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: We'll need to see a picture of your folder structure. If this command file is in a subfolder, you'll need to use `../config.json` instead of `./config.json`

Comment: i added an the img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./` references the current directory of the file it is written in. In this case, the `commands` folder. However, *`../`* will act on the directory *above* the current directory. In your situation, this is the directory with the `config.json` file.

Simply change:

```js
require('./config.json')
```

To:

```js
require('../config.json')
```

[More info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397524/what-does-the-mean-dot-slash-in-linux#:%7E:text=The%20dot%2Dslash%2C%20.%2F,slash%20is%20a%20path%20delimiter.)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the image you provided, your running script, `say.js` is located in: `/command/say.js`.

`./config.json` will look for the JSON file in `/command/config.json`, which as we clearly can see, `config.json` is not located there.

You need to go one folder up (current folder > root folder).

```js
const configuration = require("../config.json");
```